# error when try to perform CURD in mongoosedb

Tags: mongoose, next.js

## signup,tsx in this when every i try to communicat with the mongoose

## either this error in signup TypeError: newAdmin.save is not a function or TypeError: connect is not a function

```
import { useState } from "react";
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useRecoilState } from "recoil";
import { connectToDatabase } from "@/lib/dbConnect";
import { userAtom } from "@/store/atoms/userAtom";
import { User } from "@/lib/db";

export default function signup() {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [pass, setPass] = useState('');
    const [userInfo, setInfo] = useRecoilState(userAtom);
    const router = useRouter();
    console.log(userInfo);
    const handleSignup = async () => {
        try {
            console.log("conecting")
            await connectToDatabase();
            console.log("connectd!")
            const obj = { username: name, password: pass, balance: 100000, };
            const newAdmin = new User(obj);
            let adminDb = await newAdmin.save();
            console.log("saved!");
            setInfo({ username: name, balance: 100000, password: pass });
            const token = jwt.sign({ username: name }, "Umesh", { expiresIn: '1h' });
            localStorage.setItem('token', token);


            router.push("/");
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("error in signup", error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="flex justify-center mt-56">HI        </div>
    );
}
```

## this is bd.ts

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    balance: Number,
});
export const User = mongoose.models?.User || mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

## this is dbconnect.ts

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

let alreadyDone = false;

export async function connectToDatabase(){
if (alreadyDone) {
return;
>!     }
alreadyDone = true;
await mongoose.connect('URL(this is fine)', { dbName: "User" });
console.log("Connected to database successfully!");
>! }
```

## this is package.json

```
{
  "name": "401",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongodb": "^6.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.2.0",
    "next": "14.1.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "recoil": "^0.7.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.5",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

## Yes, i have try to use try and catch in every in both bb and dbconnect

## I am pleased if anybody can debug this

## I am thinking that the mongoose would conenct to the nextjs in no problem